# SPFile.CheckoutBy gives System/account instead of my login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

Description: i am user user1 (which is also the user of the app pool of sharepoint, so when i logon with user user1 it says welcome system account).

In my code, i want to test if a file is checked out by user 1, so the result of the following:

```
file.CheckedOutBy.LoginName.ToLower() == userName.ToLower())
```

is always false (which is not correct), CheckOutby value is (Sharepoint system) while username value is (user1).

How to resolve this?

Im using SP2010

Comment: Isn't this property obsolete, try using LockedByUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, this is how i solved it:

```
file.CheckedOutBy.LoginName.ToLower() == web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToLower()
```

giving sharepoint\system on both sides, which was corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the user account which is used as a app pool account, because You will always see system account. In this case the best way is to change the app pool account to another which won't be used for another purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `username` come from?

Try this:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web; //get it from somewhere
if(file.CheckedOutBy == web.EnsureUser(username)) {
    //do something
}
```

That should do the comparison on the SPUser.Id